# How to forward the interface when reverse proxy in Golang

Tags: go

I want the first 4 interfaces to be forwarded to port 6666, api/v1/test666/jiekou and api/v1/test666/jiekou1 to port 8888， but I don't know how to figure it out.

```
api/v1/test
api/v1/test/jiekou
api/v1/test666/jiekou
api/v1/test666/jiekou1
```

I hope someone can give me the specific code about it. Thanks in advance！

Comment: Some important details are missing, e.g., do you mean any specific reverse proxy (e.g. nginx)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to forward your interface, but maybe you need to add more detail about it.

Here is some code maybe you want.

```
[proxy-1]
ReqPrefix = "api/v1/:param/*path"
Target = 'your target port'//you need to change here

[proxy-2]
ReqPrefix = "api/v1/:param"
Target = 'your target port'//you need to change here

[proxy-3]
ReqPrefix = "api/v1/test666/*path"
Target = 'your target port'//you need to change here
```